# Java lang error on a WFS request in x-www-form-urlencoded when using propertyName

Tags: geoserver, wfs

Using GeoServer 2.21.2 and WFS, we are switching from doing a GET request to a POST because we're reaching the URL length limit and we're using `x-www-form-urlencoded` format, which works correctly except when we specify `propertyName` (in the format `property_a`,`property_b`): we get the following error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

If we only send a single property name we get a different error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException
```

If we don't specify `propertyName` everything works.

Any clues?

Edit: Found the problem! I was missing a "service" field with the value "WFS". Weirdly, everything works without it except "propertyName".. GeoServer quirks.

Comment: service=WFS is a requirement for all WFS requests, so GeoServer is playing loose with the standard if it allows requests without it.

Comment: unless started in cite-compliant mode then GeoServer tries to be understanding of errors

Comment: I see, yeah that's what seems to be happening. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

WFS expects your request to be an XML file, so set the appropriate mime type.

Comment: Hmm I see, I'm find it very hard to find documentation on the XML requests and can't get them to work, I was hoping x-www-form-urlencoded would work since it does seem to work for me even with complex filters, but it just clashes on propertyName.. Thank you, I'll continue battling with the XML requests.

Comment: have you read the WFS and FES standards?

Comment: Thank you, that's a good tip, adding FES to the search helped me find the documentation